# How to find location in database from my current location?

Tags: android, geolocation, location

So now i have Current location with radius 1000 meters, so i want all location from database within a radius 1000 meter from my current location will be display.

```
geoFire.setLocation("You", new GeoLocation(latitude, longtitude),
                                new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                                        //Add Marker
                                        if(mCurrent != null)
                                            mCurrent.remove(); // Remove old marker
                                        mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                .position(new LatLng(latitude,longtitude))
                                                .title("You"));

                                        radius= new LatLng(latitude,longtitude);
                                        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                                                .center(radius)
                                                .radius(1000) // in Metters
                                                .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
                                                .fillColor(0x220000FF)
                                                .strokeWidth(5.0f)
                                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `geoFire.setLocation` saved your location with key 'You'.
It will be good if you show your db structure.
But to get saved locations in some radius you need to do this:

```
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(GEOFIRE_PATH));
            GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire
                    .queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(myLocation.latitude, myLocation.longitude), RADIUS);

            geoQuery.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(new GeoQueryDataEventListener() {
                ...onData methods
            }
```

Comment: i got it, but after that, how i can compare/calculate it mylocation with location from database ? thank

Comment: why you need to "compare/calculate it"? It automatically gives locations that is in your radius that you put in `.queryAtLocation()` second parameter.